# Swift Compile Message: "'all()' is only available in macOS 12 or newer" is unclear: how do I determine OS to target?

Tags: swift, vapor

Occasionally I get this message when compiling a Vapor app, and I cannot figure out what it's referring to. I've looked in the Package for the app, and the relevant part seems to be this:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "wb2-web",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
```

which would make me think the value for .macOS is wrong, but no values I try seem to be accepted, and if this is the issue, I can't find a reference to indicate what values are legal. I'm on a machine with Ventura 13.4.1. Any changes in the package.swift result in a contextual type error.

What is going on? Or, given that it's a sporadic error while I try to sort out some Vapor issues, am I looking in the wrong place?

EDIT: when I try to access the enumerated options in place of .v10_15, this is all I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're documented in the [SupportedPlatform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/supportedplatform) docs. You should be able to Opt-click the `.macOS` symbol to jump to that in Xcode.

For macOS 12, you want [v12](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/supportedplatform/macosversion/v12):

```
   .macOS(.v12)
```

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, that the issue is that only an older target is installed But this is a Vapor project (god help me), and there's no easy configuration interface to add one... so it must be a configuration issue somewhere... but where? Changing the value to v12 threw an error immediately...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an older target is installed." You'll need to be much more specific about what error you're receiving, and in what context. Xcode 14 can build for quite old targets.

Comment: Rob Napier, the edit may or may not address what your're asking. The option you're describing does not exist.

Comment: What version of Xcode is this? You may need to increase your swift-tools-version line in order to see newer versions of the OS as well (not sure about that, but you have a very old swift-tools-version). Try 5.7.

Comment: Version 14.3.1 (14E300c). Tried updating that line to 5.7 with no change, still getting this kind of error. I'm fairly sure this is an artefact related to Vapor configuration, but I cannot find anyplace to update the target development environment.